# Discrepancy of the Keplerian speed by a factor when calculated with different methods

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I needed to derive today the Keplerian speed for a circular motion in a gravitational field. Just for the hell of it I decided to derive it once via the forces and once via the energies and strangely there is a discrepancy by a factor of $\sqrt2$ !? I must have done something wrong, so please let me know. Here are my calculations, first via the forces:

$F_{rad} = F_g$

$\frac{mv^2}{r} = G \frac{Mm}{r^2}$

$\Rightarrow v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$

All is in agreement with the Keplerian speed given in text books and wikipeadia. But let's see what happens when we derive the speed $v$ from the energies:

$E_{kin} = E_{g}$

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = G \frac{Mm}{r}$

$\Rightarrow v = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$

Now unfortunately I have a discrepancy of $v$ from the known formula by $\sqrt2$. It seems that the discrepancy would be resolved if I apply the virial theorem $E_{kin} = \frac{1}{2}E_{pot}$. But I thought the virial theorem is only to be applied to systems with many particles. In the above equations, I am only observing the velocity $v$ of a test particle around a massive central mass with $M>>m$ in a Newtonian limit. So what am I misunderstanding here? Do I really need to use the virial theorem? What is the justification for that? Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the for an orbit the kinetic energy is not equal to the potential energy.
To use conservation of energy you have to compare the energy of a system at two different instants in time.
One instant could be "the object is in a circular orbit", where
$$ E_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad E_p = -\frac{GMm}{r}$$
so
$$E_{tot} = E_k + E_p = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{GMm}{r}.$$
We can think of this as the final state of our system.
But $E_{tot}$ is not equal to zero.  You'll need another point of reference, an initial state, where you can determine $E_{tot}$ and any work done to get from your initial state to the final orbit.
Only then can you use conservation of energy to connect things.
$$E_i + W = E_f.$$

From the force perspective you can derive the relation between kinetic and potential energies of a circular orbit by substituting $E_k$ and $E_p$ into the second equation in your question.

Since $2E_k = -E_p$, we can see that the total energy of the orbiting state is negative.  This is because the system is in a bound state.
If you gave the system more energy so $E_{tot}\ge0$, you'd have an unbound state, where the orbiting body can fly off to infinite distance.

In your energy equations you implicitly solved for when $E_{tot} = 0$.
This would occur when $v\rightarrow 0$ and $r\rightarrow \infty$.
Your second solution considers the situation where the particle is a distance $r$ from the central mass and has speed $v$ at the initial point, and at the final point the particle has escaped to infinity:
$$ E_i = E_f $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{GMm}{r} = 0 $$
You found the escape velocity.

Comment: Thanks! You say "since $2E_k = -E_p$", but what is justification of this equation. I guess this is my main question

Comment: It comes from the force equations, as said in the sentence above the one you quote.

Comment: Hm, in the sentence you mention I see how $1/2mv^2=E_k$. But then I don't get the step to $2E_k = -E_p$. I guess one can use the viral theorem to justify this. But I suspect you have some other justification, that I am very curious to know, if you can walk to through a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: Much of this answer is incorrect. For example, in the last equation, the m in the kinetic energy term should be the reduced mass.

Comment: The question specifically asks about the $M\gg m$ limit. In that case $M_{tot}\approx M$ and $\mu\approx m$.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks, I think now your edited answer finds the error in my thinking - "for an orbit the kinetic energy is not equal to the potential energy". Hence, what I have written for the energies $1/2mv^2 = GMm/r$ is not correct for a Keplerian, circular orbit, but instead for a body escaping the gravitational mass $M$ at infinity

Answer (score -1):

The orbital velocity in a circular orbit is $ \sqrt{\frac{G(M+m)}{r}} $.

The escape velocity of an orbit is $ \sqrt{\frac{2G(M+m)}{r}} $.

Comment: This is not really what I have asked about, but thanks. Paul edited his answer above and he spotted my flaw in thinking about the energies